# How to send array index value into JSON body in Postman

Tags: arrays, json, rest, api, postman

I'm chaining several requests to simulate an end to end scenario in postman.

I have an array of values which was returned back from the first request. 
I've set the array as an environment variable so that it can be accessed by other subsequent requests in my collection.

```
pm.environment.set("travArray", travArray);
```

The console output of the travArray looks like:

```
0:"d4faf286-ab68-448b-87cb-ad6a7030bc57"
1:"2e21ab1f-25be-49ab-a984-db529022cf0f"
2:"9a1d942c-4048-48a7-acfc-7a1c9563c528"
```

Next, I'm trying to post a json request with each of these indexed values.
In the Body (raw) request it looks like this;

```
    "travelers": [
    {
        "id": "{{travArray[0]}}",
        "firstName": "teaaf",
        "lastName": "fadfadsfads",
        "travelerType": "ADULT"
    },
    {
        "id": "{{travArray[1]}}",
        "firstName": "sdfsfsdf",
        "lastName": "sdfsfsd",
        "travelerType": "ADULT"
    },
    {
        "id": "{{travArray[2]}}",
        "firstName": "sdfsdf",
        "lastName": "sdfsfsdf",
        "travelerType": "ADULT"
    }
],
```

But using this syntax {{travArray[1]}} fails to parse the actual value when the raw request is posted to the API endpoint.

Interestingly, when i just use {{travArray} - without the index notation, the entire contents of the array is sent.

example output:

```
id:"d4faf286-ab68-448b-87cb-ad6a7030bc57,2e21ab1f-25be-49ab-a984-db529022cf0f,9a1d942c-4048-48a7-acfc-7a1c9563c528"
firstName:"teaaf"
lastName:"fadfadsfads"
travelerType:"ADULT"
```

Can someone tell me how to parse index value of the array in the json body request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Postman scripting, so this is my noob method of doing this.

You need to pass the array location into the test script.

```js
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
    pm.environment.set("travArray", travArray[0].id);
```

You can iterate through the array by setting a variable and then using the `.setNextRequest()` method.

Set an index variable in your environment. Then set a for-in loop:

```js
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody); // Deserialize the return
    for (let traveler in jsonData) {
        pm.setNextRequest(jsonData[traveler].id);
        // do any checks/tests with the response.
    }
```

Once you've processed the other request, you can add a .setNextRequest() to the script and point it back to the first request. With the .setNextRequest(null) call, Postman will stop running the iteration.

Good luck!